# VBA Searching and creating a hyperlink

Tags: excel, vba

Okay so I have two worksheets in my excel file, `Headers` and `Info` and both are sorted via section and then subsection (albeit a bit differently. `Headers` has section 7 sub section 1 while `Info` has section 7.01 and sub section X).

So I currently have my code set up to search for the right part ( I know this through the debugging) but depending on how I alter the Search and CreateHyperlink functions I either get a run-time 5 error (for creating the hyperlink) or 1094? I think... It's been a while since I've had that error and I'll update if I find a way to reproduce it.

This is the specific spot with the errors:

```
rownumber = Range("A:A").Find(search)
Sheets("Headers").Hyperlinks.Add Sheets("Headers").Cells(i, 3), "", Sheets("Info").Cells(rownumber, 1), "", link
```

This is everything else:

```
'Create new Hyperlinks
Dim i As Integer
i = 18
Dim link As String
Dim section As String
Dim subsectiona As Integer
Dim subsection As String
Dim search As String
Dim rownumber As Integer
section = 0
subsection = 0
subsectiona = 0
Sheets("Headers").Select
    Do While Cells(i, 3).Value <> ""
        link = Cells(i, 3).Value
        section = Cells(i, 1).Value
        subsectiona = Cells(i, 2).Value
        If subsectiona = 0 Then
            subsectiona = "1"
        End If
        If subsectiona < 10 Then
            subsection = "0" & subsectiona
        Else
            subsection = subsectiona
        End If
        search = section & "." & subsection
        Sheets("Info").Select
        rownumber = Range("A:A").Find(search)
        Sheets("Headers").Hyperlinks.Add Sheets("Headers").Cells(i, 3), "", Sheets("Info").Cells(rownumber, 1), "", link
         i = i + 1
    Loop
```

As of right now it produces the the run time error 5 code and rownumber shows up as 7 when it should be 2.
Here's what the Headers file looks like:

```
Section Subsection Link Description
 7           1     Link   Links to 7.01
 7           2     Link   Links to 7.02
```

And the info file:

```
Section Subsection Type Name Description
 7.01     1         Blah Blah Blah
 7.01     2         Blah Blah Blah
 7.02     1         Blah Blah Blah
```

So the hyper link from the word "link" in cell C2 of Headers leads in this case to cell A2 of Info and the word "link" in cell C3 of Header leads to cell A4 of Info.

Any ideas as to what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you fixed.

1. Your Find returns a range and from there you can get your row
   number.
2. But also you are jumping between sheets wich is unnessesary.
3. And the hyperlink you are creating will not go to the other sheet like it looks like you want.

   ```
   Sub test()
   Dim i As Integer
   i = 2
   Dim link As String
   Dim section As String
   Dim subsectiona As Integer
   Dim subsection As String
   Dim search As String
   Dim rownumber As Integer
   Dim findResult As Range

   section = 0
   subsection = 0
   subsectiona = 0
   Sheets("Headers").Select
   Do While Cells(i, 3).Value <> ""
       rownumber = 0
       link = Cells(i, 3).Value
       section = Cells(i, 1).Value
       subsectiona = Cells(i, 2).Value
       If subsectiona = 0 Then
           subsectiona = "1"
       End If
       If subsectiona < 10 Then
           subsection = "0" & subsectiona
       Else
           subsection = subsectiona
       End If
       search = section & "." & subsection

       Set findResult = Range("Info!A1:A10000").Find(What:=search, LookIn:=xlValues, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
       If Not findResult Is Nothing Then
           rownumber = findResult.Row
           Sheets("Headers").Hyperlinks.Add Sheets("Headers").Cells(i, 3), "", Sheets("Info").Name & "!A" & rownumber, "", link
       End If

        i = i + 1
   Loop
   End Sub
   ```

**Edit:** I ended up changing a bit from my original design. Now instead of creating hyperlinks based on where the data is I have a macro set to refresh the links (for when new sections are added) and a  Worksheet_FollowHyperlink event that sorts the Info sheet based on which link was clicked. Here's my final code:

Refresh Links Macro:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
Dim i As Integer
i = 17
Dim link As String

section = 0
subsection = 0
subsectiona = 0
Sheets("Headers").Select
Do While Cells(i, 3).Value <> ""
    link = Cells(i, 3).Value
    Sheets("Headers").Hyperlinks.Add Sheets("Headers").Cells(i, 3), "", Sheets("Info").Name & "!A2", "", link
     i = i + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

And here's the event code I have on the Headers worksheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)

Dim section As String
Dim subsectiona As Integer
Dim subsection As String
Dim Row As Integer
Dim addressa As Range

    Set addressa = Target.Range
    Row = addressa.Row
    section = Cells(Row, 1).Value
    subsectiona = Cells(Row, 2).Value
    If subsectiona = 0 Then
        subsectiona = "1"
    End If
    If subsectiona < 10 Then
        subsection = "0" & subsectiona
    Else
        subsection = subsectiona
    End If
    search = section & "." & subsection
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$M$741").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=search
End Sub
```

**Thanks a lot for the help!**

Comment: Yes this worked perfectly thank you! Gonna look through it some more and make sure I understand everything you said/did.

Comment: I'm curious. Let's say I wanted to change it up and instead of just linking to that cell you link to a filtered version of the sheet based on the "search" variable. How would I do that? Link to other explantions are perfectly fine as well.

Comment: This is what I think: A hyperlink cannot filter the sheet, but a hyperlink can be cought in a vba event and through that you can create a filter on the sheet in vba.

Better solution is creating a button programatically that executes a function thats sorts the sheet based on the a dropdown value.

Comment: You can also create buttons dynamically and catch their onclik event, but its not nice code.

Comment: That is actually a quite good question. You might want to ask that.

Answer (score 0):

Find() returns a range, not a row number:

```
Sheets("Headers").Hyperlinks.Add Sheets("Headers").Cells(i, 3), _
                   "", Sheets("Info").Cells(rownumber, 1), "", link
```

should be

```
Sheets("Headers").Hyperlinks.Add Sheets("Headers").Cells(i, 3), _
                   "", rownumber, "", link
```

Should also add a check to make sure the term was actually found - otherwise rownumber will be Nothing